# need information in a BayeuxServer.Session Listener

Tags: cometd

I would like to keep information about my logged in users available in my webapp; so, for example, I pass an identifier to SessionListener.sessionAdded in the ServerMessage, and use the identifier to load user info into a persistent hash.

Likewise, when a session is destroyed, I would like to erase the client information from the hash when SessionListener.sessionRemoved is called. However, there is no message. Can I use ServerSession.getUserAgent(), and what is the String that it returns?

Or, is there one SessionListener per session, so that I can save the email locally in the SessionListener for use when sessionRemoved is called?

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 choices.

With a session attribute:

```java
class MySessionListener implements BayeuxServer.SessionListener {
    public void sessionAdded(ServerSession session, ServerMessage message) {
        session.setAttribute("token", message.getDataAsMap().get("token"));
    }
    public void sessionRemoved(ServerSession session, boolean timedout) {
        String token = (String)session.getAttribute("token");
        // Use the token here.
    }
}
```

Or with a `RemoveListener`:

```java
class MySessionListener implements BayeuxServer.SessionListener {
    public void sessionAdded(ServerSession session, ServerMessage message) {
        final String token = (String)message.getDataAsMap().get("token");
        session.addListener(new RemoveListener() {
            public void removed(ServerSession session, boolean timeout) {
                // Use token here.
            }
        });
    }
    public void sessionRemoved(ServerSession session, boolean timedout) {
        // Nothing to do here.
    }
}
```